# setting up Kallisto software

Tags: anaconda, conda, analysis

I have tried to set up  Kallisto software - following the instructions on https://protocols.hostmicrobe.org/conda without any luck. I need this software to align reads to a reference genome for RNA sequencing analysis.
It worked up until I used the command: conda create --name rnaseq on anaconda prompt (miniconda3) as it came up as an error.

Does anyone know how I might be able to correct this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please include the error from anaconda as text. This would really help in solving your problem.

Comment: Thankyou for your response. Apologises I will be able to post it in 2 hours as I'm currently on a different computer. FYI I'm working on a windows computer.

Comment: Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - kallisto

Comment: PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - kallisto

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64

Comment: - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please incorporate additional information by editing the question rather than posting in comments. Comments are great way to alert users of  when changes are made to the question, but not good for information that would clarify the original question by being included.

Comment: Bioconda does not support Windows.